# HowTO in PCF Share same jar's across multiple microservices?

Tags: java, jar, cloud-foundry

PCF

I have 200 microservices ,each independently applying 12 factors , but most of the services have to be packaged with same 3rd party libs (ex - log4j2,db drivers,POI jars.....) to be refereed.

Question : Does PCF provide a process to centrally host these jars , so they could be in classpath shared between multiple microservices, making the apps thin small size.

with regards
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You suppose to use JFrog Artifactory which is provided by Pivotal. You can check this out in Pivotal Network.

Comment: I do not intend to use another Artifactory....  All i need is to use the 3rd party libraries across my org/space from a SINGLE-HOSTED process in Pivotal-Cloud-Foundry .

Comment: I believe you're using Artifactory for your project. If yes, You can directly drop related 3rd party libraries to artifactory repository.

Comment: I use Maven Artifact,but this not the ask i am requesting. How can i share Standard same jars across  apps in PCF (222+) apps ?

Comment: are you looking to add the common jar(s) at runtime to your classpath?

Comment: I have  EACH of 27 microservices along with 100 jars packaged and deployed, If PCF can provide a process where in all the 100 jars be shared across 27 services...